# Multilevel modeling with latent variables in Mplus

Tags: multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, mplus

I have collected data points from 216 individuals. *A<sub>1</sub>*, *A<sub>2</sub>*, *A<sub>3</sub>*  are three performance measures to be combined into a latent variable *lA*. I have three observations on this measure for each individual. *U* is another measure for which I have three observations for each individual, and these observations are paired with *A<sub>1-3</sub>*.*W* is a measure for which I have *only one* observation for each individual (something like an IQ score).

Now, I would like to fit the following model:
[image]

As I understand, I have a within-subjects part (*A<sub>1-3</sub>* loading on *lA*, and *U* predicting *lA*) and a between-subjects part (*W* predicting *U* and *lA*), so I should fit a model that takes into account the nested structure of the data. In Mplus, this could be done two ways:

```
 VARIABLES:
 ...
    cluster = SUBJECT;

 ANALYSIS:
    type = complex;

 MODEL:
    lA by A1 A2 A3;
    lA on U W;
    U  on W;
```

..or..

```
 VARIABLES:
  ...
   cluster = SUBJECT;
   between  = W;

 ANALYSIS:
   type = twolevel;

 MODEL:
   %within%
   lA by A1 A2 A3;
   lA on U;

   %between%
   lAb by A1 A2 A3;
   lAb on W;
   U   on W;
```

When I run these two analyses, I receive quantitatively quite different results. For example, the path from *W* to *lA* is *0.154* (standardized) in the first but *0.589* (standardized) in the second analysis. Generally, the results of the second analysis seem odd to me.

Btw, the difference between the two analyses is very small, if I do not model a latent variable *lA* but, instead, combine the three indicators into a composite variable.

Why do these models differ so much?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of blog entries by Andrew Gelman about this issue: http://andrewgelman.com/2007/11/28/clustered_stand/ , http://andrewgelman.com/2009/08/21/clustered_stand_1/.

If you add complex (and don't have weights) then all that Mplus will do is correct your standard errors - the estimates should stay the same. If you use multilevel models, you model the random effects and this can change things (and did, in your example).

Also, I would not compare the standardized estimates, as these will change with the variances (which can be a bit weird in multilevel models) but compare the unstandardized estimates.